# How to clear/empty a file that is already open C++

Tags: c++, file

So, I am writing a code that takes some data from a file, does some changes(erase some things etc) and then return the new data at the same file....but before it return them, I want to clear/empty the file, so it can have only the new data...
clear() is not working...and I can't use fstream or sth like this because I have the file already.
Anyone who has any idea?

This is one of my functions that actually here I am changing the data my file has. The file is opened in an another function and then I call this function with a reference.

`void TakeSizeOnly(fstream &takememoryfile)  {`

```
string ignore_me,textsize;
while (takememoryfile >> ignore_me, takememoryfile >> ignore_me, getline(takememoryfile, textsize)) 
{
        textsize.erase(std::remove(textsize.begin(), textsize.end(), ' '), textsize.end()); //erase -> '  from every number
        cout<<textsize<<endl; //check the result by printing it on command
                        
}
```

`}`

I actually do this in oe part of my other function:

```
fstream f2qspi("str_qspi.txt");

TakeSizeOnly(f2qspi);

f2qspi.close();
```

Comment: Please inlcude a minimal reproducible example of what you've tried. This is not a code writing website

Comment: "is not working" is not a problem description, either. You should explain exactly what happens and why that is wrong.

Comment: I posted two parts from my code, but unfortunately I cannot post all the code. And of course I am not asking from anyone to write a whole code for me, I am asking if there is any ready function to do what I want. Also, by saying is not working, I mean that using clear(), I am not seeing any difference in my file, I am just viewing the new data and the old data together.

Answer (score 3):

You can't clear the file while it is open. You will first need to close your file as follows:

`file.close();`

Then you can open it in either of the following ways:

`file.open ("Demo", std::ios::out);`

OR

`file.open ("Demo", std::ios::in | std::ios::trunc);`

Comment: ohh okay!!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well if your clearing all the contents of the file you need to close the file by using close() method and then if you open the file again the file will be empty because the file pointer will start at the top of the file. Hope it works.

Comment: It works like this, but I wanted to find a way to not close the file if it's possible. But thank you anyway for your fast reply!